# Why is isset($_SESSION['username'] is returning false in my php script

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my PHP login on my STRATO server. When I am hosting it locally everything is working fine, but with STRATO not. I think it is because of the session. This is my code for it:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
header('Location: my.php');

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Because you called `session_start()` twice.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. The code is in two files, the first session in file1 (login) second session in file2 (after login).